# dagre-d3 links and labels are not appearing in angular project

Tags: angular, d3.js, graph, dagre-d3, dagre

I'm working on dagre-d3 in angular. And got stuck in the middle.

Problems:

1. Links are not appearing between the nodes.
2. Labels on the nodes are not visible.

https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-graph-kq2nb

I have gone through some of the posts related to this but not able to find what I'm missing.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you already found the answer. You just need to put ":host /deep/" before css attribute.

```
:host /deep/.edgePath path {
  stroke: #333;
  fill: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1HbI.png)